# Need a JFrame to follow a desktop

Tags: java

I have made a program which is a clock widget on your desktop that looks like this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOJgq.jpg) but I would like to have it move to whatever desktop you are on so that it pretty much follows you in a way. I work on mac and this is intended to be used on mac however it will run no problem on a pc.

The code can all be found on [here](https://github.com/Eohayon/Digital-Clock-Java) for convenience sake

Thanks

Comment: Um, if i may ask... What do you mean "follow"?

Comment: @MouseEvent I would like to have the clock be on every desktop in a way. As you can see [here][http://imgur.com/a/CXbgc] it is only on desktop 3 but I would like it to be there if i switched to any other desktop.

Comment: If you wrap your jar in a proper mac application (.app) using Jar Bundler, you can right-click the dock icon to assign it to "all desktops"

Comment: It actually is a mac application right now and that doesn't seem to work @qxz

Comment: You're running it as a .app? In what way does it "not work"?

Comment: it still sticks to the one desktop. I will upload the app to my github @qxz

Comment: @qxz Is there a way to programatically fix this issue?

Comment: Not that I know of. You'd almost certainly be digging into native OSX code; there isn't anything for this in the standard library.